# Image does not show using css

Tags: html, css

Why is it that I cannot see the images using my code below. I am trying to load it via css file. the main.css is where the index.php is located as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Red Stone One Stop Shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css " />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scaleable=no">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    
    </script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="/ecommerce/index.php" class="navbar-brand" id="text">Red Stone One Stop Shop</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- Dropdown menu -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="text">Men  <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pants</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
    <!--Inserting Images-->
    <div id="background-image">
        <div id="image-1"></div>
        <div id="image-2"></div>
    </div>
    <p>
        What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the main.css File

```
body{
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#navbar{
    /*background color: #FFF0000;*/
    background-color: #800000;
}

/*change color to white*/
#text{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#background-image{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 700px;
    background-position: top center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#image-1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%
    height: 350px; 
    background-image: url(../images/ecommerce2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-size: auto 200px;
    top: -100px;
    left: -25px;
}

#image-2{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%
    height: 190px; 
    background-image: url(../images/ecommerce1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-size: 50% 200px;
    top: 80%;
    margin-top: -90px;
}
```

I can see the background but the 2 images are not showing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: try to add z-index to two images (#image-2 & #image-1)

Comment: Is the path correct ../images/background.jpg? When you consider where you are accessing the page from?

Comment: Try applying a positive z-index to the two foreground images

Comment: How do you that? How to add z-index? New to css.

Comment: The path is correct because I am able to see the background. It's just the 2 images that I can't.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 should it just be /images rather than ../images? What is your folder structure?

Comment: I placed the z-index: 20px; in the #image-1 & #image-2

Comment: @Corporalis: The index is directly inside the root folder. The 2 images are inside the images folder.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 okay, so using /images instead of ../images should work.

Answer (score 1):

css syntax error you missing semicolon `;` on width attribute

```
#image-1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px; 
    background-image: url(../images/ecommerce2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-size: auto 200px;
    top: -100px;
    left: -25px;
}

#image-2{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 190px; 
    background-image: url(../images/ecommerce1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-size: 50% 200px;
    top: 80%;
    margin-top: -90px;
}
```

Comment: I see that thank you but why is it that I only see one image?

Comment: you see main background image(#background-image) there are no any error.

Answer (score 0):

Update your ***"#image-2"*** and ***"#image-1"*** like this,

**IMPORTANT :** Add **"left:50%"** in ***#image-2***

```
#image-2 {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 190px;
background-image: url(https://blogs.thegospelcoalition.org/erikraymond/files/2015/10/i-love-you.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left bottom;
background-size: 50% 200px;
top: 80%;
margin-top: -90px;
left: 50%;
}

#image-1 {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 350px;
background-image: url(http://www.thephotoargus.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/I-Love-You-Photography-33.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left bottom;
background-size: auto 200px;
top: -157px;
left: 0px;
}
```

```css
body{
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#navbar{
    /*background color: #FFF0000;*/
    background-color: #800000;
}

/*change color to white*/
#text{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#background-image{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url(http://media-s3.blogosfere.it/vitadicoppia/images/separarsi%20dopo%20pochi%20mesi.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 700px;
    background-position: top center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#image-1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    background-image: url(http://www.thephotoargus.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/I-Love-You-Photography-33.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-size: auto 200px;
    top: -157px;
    left: 0px;
}

#image-2{
        position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 190px;
    background-image: url(https://blogs.thegospelcoalition.org/erikraymond/files/2015/10/i-love-you.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-size: 50% 200px;
    top: 80%;
    margin-top: -90px;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Red Stone One Stop Shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css " />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scaleable=no">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    
    </script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="/ecommerce/index.php" class="navbar-brand" id="text">Red Stone One Stop Shop</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- Dropdown menu -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="text">Men  <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pants</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
    <!--Inserting Images-->
    <div id="background-image">
        <div id="image-1"></div>
        <div id="image-2"></div>
    </div>
    <p>
        What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```